# Search suggestions with custom listview like Google Search app

Tags: android, android-custom-view, searchview

I want my recent search suggestions [using Action Bar Sherlock SearchView] to display in a custom list view. The default one has a timer/clock icon on the left and the recent query(text) on it's right.

I want to do something like the Google Search app, [here's a screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-RotDYXFOcvo/Tw7AuyLjD4I/AAAAAAAAUqU/YsazUfiqEgA/s320/Google-Search-App-Screenshot-01.jpg).

On clicking the arrow on the right, only the search field is filled with the query and search action is not taken. On clicking on the item(text) in listview, the search intent is called.

I've implemented search and suggestions, just want to create a custom listview for suggestions.

Can anyone help me here?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @droidster, I am dealing with similar issue. Did you ever figured out how to customize the listview for suggestions?

Comment: No @SherCoder Couldn't figure out a solution. Suggestions show up as a normal list. No arrow that fills the search field, selecting the item starts a search.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's pretty late, but I'm posting this so this may help someone in future. You could actually enable the arrow on the right side of the suggestion with just one line.
It's called query refinement. Enabling query refinement will display the arrow, which on clicking will rewrite your query text, which then you can edit and later submit. Here's an example from my project.

```
searchView.apply {
            setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
            isQueryRefinementEnabled = true
        }
```

The important part here, is the **isQueryRefinementEnabled = true**

Comment: Thank you! It works! In java you do it like this `searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to make a custom list adapter.

See here how to make that.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/661074

Then, In your adapter you'll have a onClick() listener for that "right arrow". In the listener, I'd fire off an event that notifies the activity.

This is a very nice library for event messaging.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Your activity will then receive the message with the data about the clicked item.  Use that data to populate your search field.

Comment: Hey @Kent, Thanks for the answer. But how do you link the Suggestions Provider and the custom list view?

Comment: If you are trying to create that list based off of a custom dataset, say some list in a database, then you will have to pass that data into the custom list constructor. Then use a TextWatcher to filter the data

Comment: If you are just trying to get it to complete anything the user might be typing, then I'd use a AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Hello @Kent, I am using the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider. Is there an easy way to customize the layout? The data is there in the content provider. Also, I'm using ABS 4.3 SearchView. I'm sorry I couldn't understand how AutoCompleteTextView can work here. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I haven't ever actually used the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider. But from a couple of google searches it seems to me that you could use this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html   I'd read the "action key" section.  It seems like thats what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

May help someone, This is exactly what the question is asking for.
http://www.shmoula.cz/howto-access-recent-query-suggestions-on-android-and-populate-listview-with-them/

The main idea is to query the  SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider and populate the list. we can do so like this,

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

String contentUri = "content://" + MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY + '/' + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, new String[] { query }, null);
```